# How can I pass some textes with form.Controls.Add(page.LoadControl)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am gonna pass some texts and images address from aspx file to ascx file  with page.loadControl function.

in my aspx file I have this line  code :

```
form.Controls.Add(page.LoadControl("~/Controls/Shared/NoResults.ascx"));
```

How can I pass my data with  page.loadControl  which is located in aspx to  userControl ?
and How can I use in ascx?

```html
internal string RenderList()
        {
            ConstructGrid();
            SetSort();
        
            var page = new Page() { EnableViewState = false };
            var form = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm();
            page.Controls.Add(form);
            if (Data != null && Data.PageInfo != null && Data.PageInfo.TotalRecords > 0)
    {
  form.Controls.Add(this);
   DataBind();
     }
    else
                form.Controls.Add(page.LoadControl("~/Controls/Shared/NoResults.ascx"));
  return ControlLoader.RenderCustomControl(page);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to expose a public property in the .ascx file and assign the desired values to the respective properties.

```
    internal string RenderList()
            {
                ConstructGrid();
                SetSort();

                var page = new Page() { EnableViewState = false };
                var form = new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm();
                page.Controls.Add(form);
                if (Data != null && Data.PageInfo != null && Data.PageInfo.TotalRecords > 0)
        {
      form.Controls.Add(this);
       DataBind();
         }
        else
               var noResultsControl  =  (Page.LoadControl("~/Controls/Shared/NoResults.ascx") as NoResults)  
noResultsControl.PropertyOne =  "Sample"  ;
    form.Controls.Add(noResultsControl);
      return ControlLoader.RenderCustomControl(page);
            }
```

Comment: how can i use in pageload in ascx??

Comment: what about using :form.Controls.Add(page.LoadControl("~/Controls/Shared/NoResults.ascx",  initParams));